# Cannot exit sftp

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sftp

I'm having some major issues with sftp. Currently I can transfer files to and from the server just fine but I cannot actually exit; typing `exit` or `bye` does not return me to my PC's shell but just hangs there.

```
    komali{Void}:~ λ sftp -v komali@192.168.68.111
    OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Connecting to 192.168.68.111 [192.168.68.111] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    ....
    Connected to 192.168.68.111.
    sftp> # everything working
    sftp> exit
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
    
    (ctrl + c)
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt  


More full output with -v below

    komali{Void}:~ λ sftp -v komali@192.168.68.111
    OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Connecting to 192.168.68.111 [192.168.68.111] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/komali/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
    debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7 pat OpenSSH_7.4* compat 0x04000006
    debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.68.111:22 as 'komali'
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/komali/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:DDC3lEDZrZUU8ie5x9drI6qs9sEr8HG1Dcgj6QVmIRc
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/komali/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: Host '192.168.68.111' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/komali/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:J640EIUDOZpZ6kf33Cdr9dJ7XAFMNznSu6zRnEJPuT4
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:J640EIUDOZpZ6kf33Cdr9dJ7XAFMNznSu6zRnEJPuT4
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/komali/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    komali@192.168.68.111's password: 
    Authenticated to 192.168.68.111 ([192.168.68.111]:22) using "password".
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: pledge: filesystem
    debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
    debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/komali/.ssh/known_hosts for 192.168.68.111 / (none)
    debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/komali/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 192.168.68.111 / (none)
    debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/komali/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
    debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
    debug1: client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server used untrusted RSA signature algorithm ssh-rsa for key 0, disregarding
    debug1: update_known_hosts: known hosts file /home/komali/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
    Connected to 192.168.68.111.
    sftp> # everything working
    sftp> exit
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
    
    
    
    
    
    
    (ctrl + c)
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt  
    Interrupt
```

ssh works as intended.

The only way I can exit is killing the sftp process manually and I would not like to rely on that as I have scripts to automate file transfer to and from the server.
My server (formerly Laptop) is running a Debian WSL1 instance and was working perfectly well up until this morning. I can sftp into my Raspberry Pi just fine and cannot sftp into the server from there either. I have no idea what is going on so if anyone has any suggestions I'd love to hear them. I'm also not sure what to add so if any further information is needed I will edit this post. Thanks!

Comment: the `quit` command. Also, as to your other question in order to sftp from a computer to a computer, you have to be able to ssh from that computer to that computer..  You sftp after you have ssh sorted out.

Comment: So, are you saying that after you type exit,(or quit), then you lose the sftp prompt, and then you do ctrl-c and each time you do ctrl-c  it keeps writing the word "interrupt"?!

Comment: Do you have something in your shell startup files (.bashrc and so on) on the remote system which launches a process in the background when you connect?

Comment: Yes; the only way to exit is to kill the sftp process. ssh works perfectly fine and exits without issue. I’m only running small tasks in the background (feh, picom, etc) and nothing that connects to the internet

Answer (score 0):

#### Hypothesis

The server uses some kind of wrapper over `sftp-server` (or a replacement) that runs something asynchronously and does not terminate when you expect. The stdout of this extra process is connected to the same pipe the `sftp-server` uses; the process is silent and does not break the protocol, but holds the pipe open after the `sftp-server` exits.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346566/108618):

> `sshd` does wait for the process in which it has started the user's login shell, but also, after that process has terminated waits for eof on the stdout pipe (not the stderr pipe in the case of openssh at least).
>
> And eof happens when there's no file descriptor by any process open on the writing end of the pipe, which typically only happens when all the processes that didn't have their stdout redirected to something else are gone.

---

#### Proof of concept

An OpenSSH server configured (in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) with

```
subsystem sftp sleep 15 & /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

will replicate the behavior you described, if you type `exit` before 15 seconds pass. The connection will last at least 15 seconds.

Like the linked answer states, it's about the stdout. It's enough to redirect the stdout of the extra process to elsewhere and the problem is gone:

```
subsystem sftp sleep 15 >/dev/null & /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

<sub>(If you want to test this in your SSH server then remember you need to reload the service after you edit the file; e.g. `sudo systemctl reload sshd.service`.)</sub>

---

#### Conclusion

*If the hypothesis is right*, the problem is in the server. The extra process is probably not `sleep`, but it's something. If you can reconfigure the server then maybe you can fix it:

- by not starting any extra process(es) in the first place
- or by redirecting the stdout of the extra process(es)
- or by (somehow) making the extra process(es) terminate when `sftp-server` terminates.

*If the hypothesis is right*, I think there is no simple client-side solution.

However I don't know what could have made Debian WSL1 instance start behaving like this on its own. Maybe it's not about the SSH server per se. Any server-side process that manages to open the relevant pipe for writing can be a culprit. It does not have to be a descendant of the SSH server, it may be a rogue process.

Comment: I will test this when I get home, although I’m not sure if this is what happened. This server is just my old laptop with a dead screen that I started web server on a couple weeks ago and I haven’t touched my ssh/sshd configs

Comment: confirmed; my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (with comments removed) is`ChallengeResponseAuthentication no \n UsePAM yes \n X11Forwarding yes \n PrintMotd no \n AcceptEnv LANG LC_* \n Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
`

Comment: @PrinceKomali What if you use `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`?